# General solution of the four-vector with each component satisfying the wave-equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, waves, polarization

Maybe this is more appropriate for Math stackexchange, but this question regards the solution we use in order to find representation for massive / massless spin-1 particle.

When $$(\Box + m^2)A_\mu = 0$$
for $\mu = 0,1,2,3$, general solution is of the form

$$A_\mu(x) = \Sigma_i \int \frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} a_i(\vec{p})\epsilon_\mu^i(p)e^{ipx}$$
Why? I have not studied partial differential equations enough to know why this polarization vector is necessary. Even a reference would be helpful, since I just could not find a place to read about this.

Comment: I've not studied QFT, but that looks a lot like [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function).

Comment: The polarisation vector has nothing to do with the equation, it's just the collection of the four a priori independent expansion coefficients into a single vector. Also, your integration measure is missing a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}$ to be Lorentz invariant.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Greens functions don't concern a differential equation which is homogenous everywhere. Regarding thread pointing out that $(ip)^2=-m^2$ might help.

Comment: You have a linear equation that is solved by plane waves. The general solution is then just a superposition of such plane waves. It's basically just a Fourier transform of the k-space solution.

Comment: @NikolajK: This is true, but not having studied QFT, I'm not familiar with the homogeneity of this equation versus the Helmholtz equation that it looks like. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Mhm, how do you define homogeneity, if you have to know the equation to see it it's homogenous? If $D$ is any operator, the equation $D\phi=0$ is homogenous w.r.t. $\phi$ and the equation $D\phi=f$ (where $f$ a function of $\phi$) isn't. Btw. the field $A(x):=\int B(p)\,{\mathrm e}^{i\,p,x}\,{\mathrm d}p$ is also a solution to the Helmholtz equation $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+k^2)A(x)=0$, if $p^2=k^2$ for each $p$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I am wondering why $\epsilon^i_\mu(\vec{p})$ is necessary, this had to be introduced in order to talk about little group and this was referred to as 'polarization vector' at many places, for instance, by Srednicki.